# Any reason why detect mobile js is not working for android on my site?

Tags: javascript, android, mobile

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/detectmobile.js"></script>
<script>
    try {
        // This is the URL where mobile
        detectmobile.defaultMobileURL = "http://www.nsahaiku.net/mobile.php";
        detectmobile.process();
    } catch (e) {
        // Make sure that in the fault modes
        // we do not interrupt execution of other Javascript code
    }
</script>
```

No dice for www.nsahaiku.net, I get a bunch of jargon looking crud on my android browser :( Works just fine for iPhone...